# How to find which "package can be updated"?

Tags: updates, package-management

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2. Sometimes after connecting with the instance I get the following

```
7 packages can be updated.
4 updates are security updates.
```

How can I find which packages can be updated? Can I choose if don't wish to update some packages?

Comment: Question: how do I see the number of packages that can be updated after I have connected to the server. It pops up when I first connect but how I do I see it afterwards? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see what updates are available by typing as `sudo aptitude`.

For example,

[image: aptitude]

And if you don't want any package to update, then you can lock that package.

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `sudo -s` and hit enter
3. Enter your password for sudo

   ```
   echo libxfont1 hold | dpkg --set-selections
   ```
4. Replace **libxfont1** with the package you want to pin
5. Now run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

For more information, check [how to pin packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

Answer (score 12):

To do a simulated update: `sudo apt-get -s upgrade`
To update only a single package: `sudo apt-get upgrade packagename_here`

Answer (score 5):

Please do this

```
sudo cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
```

then check what packages are available for upgrade

`apt list --upgradable`

then just install what you need from the outcome above

`sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

You can hold any certain package, this will keep it at the same version no matter what.

First run `sudo -s`, then `echo package_name hold | dpkg --set-selections`.

You can then remove the hold with `sudo apt-get install package_name`.

Hope that helps.